# Error from Visual Studio Code Logic Apps? "you must have the .NET Core SDK installed"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, azure-logic-apps, .net-core-sdk

I've built a brand new windows 11 image (I use parallels) and installed all the prerequisites from this [article](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code) in an attempt to get a development environment where I can run local Logic App (standard).

After installing all prerequisites, the article describes the steps to create a sample application. On the step to create the stateless workflow, an error is shown in visual studio code in the bottom right corner of the application:

*You must have the [.NET Core SDK](https://aka.ms/AA4ac70) installed to perform this operation. See [here](https://aka.ms/AA1tpij)for supported versions.*

I manually installed .Net Core SDK. The results are shown below (note that Visual Studio 20xx is not installed on this machine, just visual studio code)

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>
> Studio\2019\BuildTools>dotnet --info .NET SDK (reflecting any
> global.json):  Version:   6.0.302  Commit:    c857713418
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.22621
> OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\
>
> global.json file:   Not found
>
> Host:   Version:      6.0.7   Architecture: x64   Commit:
> 0ec02c8c96
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 6.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>
> Download .NET:   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
>
> Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info

I've restarted my host machine, the VM image several times, stopped and restarted visual studio code.  Nothing has worked.  Is there additional information in logs to determine why visual studio code thinks the SDK is not installed? Or is there a particular version of the SDK required?

Comment: can you confirm that you're doing this on your local machine or in Azure Virtual Machine?

Comment: You keep mentioning VS Code but you're command line ouput shows Visual Studio 2019 on the path. Which one is it? They are very different.

Comment: @phuzi, note that Visual Studio 20xx is not installed on this machine, just visual studio code. I assume the reference to 2019 has something to do with installing .NET core 6

Answer (score 4):

The extension also checks if you have .NET Core 3.1 installed.
Had the same issue this morning and resolved it by also installing .NET Core 3.1

EDIT: Seems that LA Standard doesn't support Functions runtime 4 / .NET 6 at this moment. So that explains why it doesn't work with .NET 6 alone. See here: https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues/434